# EBS Volumes Mounted On Wrong Directory After Reboot

Tags: mount, raid, fstab, xfs

I have three EBS RAID 10 volumes in my /etc/fstab on an Amazon AMI hosted with AWS/EC2...

Everytime I reboot the instance, the volumes get mounted to the wrong mount points. Any ideas on how I can get these RAID volumes to mount to the correct mount points?

Correct Example

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  1.3G  6.6G  16% /
tmpfs                 3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md127            2.0G  129M  1.9G   7% /mnt/db
/dev/md126             35G   18G   18G  50% /mnt/web
/dev/md125            3.0G  267M  2.8G   9% /mnt/bc
```

After Reboot

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  1.3G  6.6G  16% /
tmpfs                 3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md127            2.0G  129M  1.9G   7% /mnt/bc
/dev/md126             35G   18G   18G  50% /mnt/db
/dev/md125            3.0G  267M  2.8G   9% /mnt/web
```

My /etc/fstab

```
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
/dev/md127  /mnt/db     xfs     defaults        0   0
/dev/md126  /mnt/web    xfs     defaults        0   0
/dev/md125  /mnt/bc    xfs     defaults        0   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### blkid

Instead of the device handles you might want to try using the UUID for each of the devices. You can get the devices UUID's using the command `blkid`.

```
$ blkid
/dev/lvm-raid2/lvm0: UUID="2123d4567-1234-1238-adf2-687a3c237f56" TYPE="ext3"
```

Then add this to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=2123d4567-1234-1238-adf2-687a3c237f56    /mnt/db     ext3     defaults        0   0
```

#### RAID Name?

@Patrick mentioned in the comments to create a RAID volume name. I was reluctant to suggest this because I quit honestly didn't understand your setup. But I'll include the details for creating the MD device just in case. Something like this:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/mdraid10 --name=myraid10 --update=name \
         /dev/md125 /dev/md126 /dev/md127
```

I've been using RAIDs for 10+ years and I've never set the name of the device though. I usually use the UUID or the actual device handle of the RAIDs instead.

#### Example

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdb1[1]
      2930266432 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

From the above output, the device handle is `/dev/md0`. So now you can check it's details:

```
$ mdadm --detail /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Wed Dec 16 22:55:51 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2930266432 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : -1
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Jul 20 07:39:34 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 2f2b26fd:ce4d985f:6a98fc18:3e8f2e46
         Events : 0.23914

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

I then typically add the above UUID to `/etc/mdadm.conf` using this command:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=2f2b26fd:ce4d985f:6a98fc18:3e8f2e46 

$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

In my `/etc/fstab` to mount this RAID I'd use `/dev/md0`:

```
/dev/md0        export/raid1 ext3    defaults            1 2
```

I also always put LVM on top of my RAIDs. But that's another topic altogether.

#### References

- [How To Use UUID To Mount Partitions / Volumes Under Ubuntu Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/)

Comment: Or name the raid volume and use `/dev/md/myname`.

Comment: Nothing to add, but I wanted to tell you this was a well though out and helpful answer.

Comment: In your first example, `blkid` reports a fs type of `ext3`, but then in the suggested fstab entry, you're mounting it as `xfs`. Assuming that's just a typo?

Comment: @aidan - thanks for the head up. Fixed the typo.